# Using a Renesas evaluation board as a Programmer

Tags: programmer, board, renesas

I am new to using renesas microcontrollers, and could use some advice from someone with experience using them. I found this [rl78 evaluation board](https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/renesas-electronics/rtk5rlg140c00000bj/renesas-electronics-rl78-g14-evaluation-kit/1950709) and a quick reading of the [product description on the renesas website](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/software-tools/boards-and-kits/eval-kits/rl78-g14-fast-prototyping-board.html) mentions that "It has a built-in emulator circuit that is equivalent to an E2 emulator Lite so you can write/debug programs without additional tools".

My question is, once i begin prototyping on the controller existing on the board, is it possible for me to use this evaluation board as a programmer to flash code to renesas rl78 controllers on other PCBs and use the same debugging/emulation features? Or would i have to get an E2 Lite programmer which is way more expensive?

If i can use it as a programmer, i could use some pointers on how i could do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Renesas development tools for the RL78 seem to me to be quite complex to use. Unless you have a very compelling need to use the RL78 I would recommend you avoid this 16-bit class controller.

The RL78 architecture is very odd. The code generation can be very inefficient when the code binary grow beyond 64K bytes.

If I recall correctly the RAM address space is a maximum of 64K bytes, and most controllers are have much less actual RAM. The maximum offered for the RL78/G14 is 48K bytes.

You should really consider almost any other controller to learn about.